# Processing huge bitmaps

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, gdi

I need to show bitmaps on my MFC/WinAPI application window. The bitmap size may be various - for instance 40MB, 100MB, 500MB, 700MB, 1GB, and more. Huge bitmaps that don't fit into the application window should be shown with scrollbars.

The issue is the system can't create a bitmap for some huge sizes even if memory is allocated via `CreateFileMapping`+`CreateDIBSection`.

Is there an approach to process such cases? I guess I need to divide my bitmaps on many small pieces, but I'm not sure this is the right way.

Comment: I would seriously consider a paging technique (esp. for the very large images!): consider a game, only a fraction of the textures (the ones you see) are ever loaded at once. Also, techniques like "lower resolution versions" are used for things in the distance or (also perhaps "while loading") in this case. Of course, that complicates the matter somewhat, and it *especially* makes some image formats hard to decode/load in chunks ... e.g. find library that already does this or write -- but not really! too complex! -- your own :-) (But perhaps pre-split or a format friendly with massive images?)

Comment: The WIC api is good at handling enormous bitmaps.  Getting a 64-bit version of Windows is the quick solution.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719655%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What size of a bitmap is not available for you to create? The limit you are likely to hit is virtual address space, which for 32-bit code is 2GB, 3GB or 4GB - depending on environment. The most straightforward solution is to move to 64-bit code.

To present this image you will perhaps want to implement a custom window/control which blits a portion of the source image into client area, and will manage scroll bars to enable user to navigate through the image. It is unlikely that there is any specificity in implementing such window compared to scollbar-enabled windows being developed for years. [Scroll Bar Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff486021%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) get you this.

**Update on `CreateFileMapping`/`MapViewOfFile`**:

The memory you allocate with `CreateFileMapping` is not immediately mapped into process address space and this leaves you an option to allocate more than you can map. Note that Windows is not actually reserving real pages when satisfying the allocation request, the system only checks that such allocation is possible and will effectively allocate on demand later.

You can use this simple probe tool [FileMappingVirtualAddress.exe](http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/FileMappingVirtualAddress/Win32/Release%20with%20Large%20Address%20Aware/FileMappingVirtualAddress.exe?format=raw) to see how the whole thing works and sort of estimate how much you can allocate in your app. The utility does as many `CreateFileMapping` 256 MB blocks on startup as possible, and by checking a box manually you do `MapViewOfFile` on already existing file mapping. You will be able to see that the real limit is virtual address space (2, 3 or 4 GB depending on environment) but it does not mean you cannot allocate more.

[image]

Also note that if you request `MapViewOfFile` for a large block, the systems needs to satisfy this with a contiguous address block, so this address space needs to be available and space fragmentation might be a problem.

With large bitmap you can make it in a way that you actually don't need the full bitmap all the time and you can process the image tile by tile.

You can also trunctate download link and browse Trac for 64-bit version and 32-bit version built without [/LARGEADDRESSAWARE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz223b1z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to see how they are different in action.

Comment: The size of the bitmap that fails on create is ~700MB. I've successfully create a handle for that size via CreateFileMapping, but CreateDIBSection fails (returns null). I have WinXP 32bit with 3,5GB RAM, virtual memory is set to 4GB.

Comment: Virtual address space limit in 32-bit XP is 2 GB per process by default. You can extend it to 3GB using so called 4GB RAM Tuning http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291988 `CreateFileMapping` can allocate you more (even more 4GB actually) but you won't be able to map the whole thing into your process with `MapViewOfFile`, you will have to do it part by part.

Comment: How can I know the maximum size MapViewOfFile can map? (Is is ~670MB on my system, but I suppose it varies on different systems.)

Comment: I updated the answer above to be able to provide you with a screenshot and the links. You can play with this tool to check how much you can allocate.

Answer (score 0):

Total GDI resources and single bitmap size are restricted resources in Windows. At the same time, plain array size is restricted only by virtual address space and available physical memory. So, you need to keep the whole image as plain array of pixels, converting only required part to GDI bitmap for display.

Comment: Array size isn't restricted by physical memory.  And will never be close to the virtual address space size.  The largest hole in the address space that's available to create a *contiguous* chunk of memory is around 650 megabytes on most 32-bit Windows installs.  The address space gets fragmented by code and heaps.  SysInternals' VMMap provides insight.

Comment: Well, I didn't say that maximal array size is equal to virtual address space or physical memory. I mean, virtual address space and physical memory are the factors restricting array size. And array size is less restricted than GDI resources - it is possible to keep more pixels in plain array, than in GDI bitmap.